# Instagram API giving BadStatusLine errors when called from server

Tags: python, instagram, python-requests

We have been running an app with several real-time subscriptions to various hashtags on Instagram. When we receive a subscription notification from Instagram, we automatically request the new images through the API. This has been working fine for several months, until suddenly yesterday the server started spewing out httplib.BadStatusLine errors on ~half of our API calls *from the server only* - at least, whenever I attempted to call the same API endpoints with the exact same parameters (including client_id) from my laptop, they'd work fine. The exact error message is:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/tags/{whatever}/media/recent?min_tag_id={whatever}&client_id={our client id} (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: '')
```

Note that it doesn't seem to be about rate limiting - at least, when I call the API from my laptop and examine the X-ratelimit-remaining header, it's generally in the 4900s.

What could be going on here? Is this happening for anyone else?

Comment: Is there a firewall or proxy in between? A bad status line usually means the connection was closed too early for a proper status line to be received.

Comment: Nothing that should be affecting outbound HTTP requests. Though I've been trying it more from my laptop and have been getting occasional 504 errors, which I'm guessing is the same issue so I assume this actually isn't limited to the server after all.